# Authenticate Google Cloud service account on docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm finding different behavior from within and outside of a docker image for authenticating a google service account.

Outside. Succeeds.

```
C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth activate-service-account 773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file C:/Users/Ben/Dropbox/Google/MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json --project api-project-773889352370
Activated service account credentials for: [773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Run docker container, pass the .json key to tmp directory.

```
C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>docker run -it -v C:/Users/Ben/Dropbox/Google/MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json:/tmp/MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json  --rm -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" --entrypoint=/bin/bash  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local-20161227
```

From within docker, confirm the file is there

```
root@4a4a9314f15c:/tmp# ls
MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json  npm-24-b7aa1bcf  npm-45-fd13ef7c  npm-7-22ec336e
```

Run the same command as before. Fails.

```
root@4a4a9314f15c:/tmp# gcloud auth activate-service-account 773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccoun
t.com --key-file MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json --project api-project-773889352370
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid.
```

What might cause this error? More broadly, what is the [suggested strategy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker) for passing credentials. I've tried this and it fails as well. I'm using the cloudml API and cloud vision, and i'd like to avoid manual gcloud init at the beginning of every run.

EDIT: To show gcloud info

```
root@7ff49b26484f:/# gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic (1/1 checks) passed.
```

confirmed same behavior

```
root@7ff49b26484f:/tmp# gcloud auth activate-service-account 773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json --project api-project-773889352370
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Failed to activate the given service account. Please ensure provided key file is valid.
```

Comment: This error is produced when gcloud tries to an get access token. Do you have network connectivity and/or a proxy setup from the container. Can you run `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` ?

Comment: Edited to add gcloud info. Is there something I need to add to docker run to allow access (to a given port?).

Comment: Also running into this issue, looks like a web login needs to be run at least once: _"[You only need to run the command once per local user environment.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#getting_credentials_for_server-centric_flow#local_development)"_

Comment: thanks @CoreyRowell , but that really hurts non-interactive runs. What if you want to push to compute engine? How to pass credentials?

Comment: @bw4sz I can attach to the container `docker run -i -t <container-id> /bin/bash` and the web login and key-file auth both work, just not as you said in non-interactive runs.

Comment: verified it works after I restarted the doc for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to put the credential in the image from the beginning? Is that a similar outcome?

On the other hand, have you tried using `--key-file /tmp/MeerkatReader-d77c0d6aa04f.json`? Since it appears you're putting the json file in `/tmp`.

You might also consider checking the network configuration inside the container and with docker from the outside.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably due to a clock skew of the docker VM. I debugged the activate-service-account function of the google SDK and got the following error message:

```
There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant:  
Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe
Please run:
$ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a different account:

$ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

After rebooting the VM, it worked like a charm.

Comment: same issue here - clock was a few minutes ahead!

Comment: Checked `date` in docker, was wrong, restarted docker VM and is fixed. Thanks

Comment: Invalid JWT token is generally related to clock drift in Docker, which might be related to this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2076

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a workload identity provider, and I made a little mistake, I set the workload provider with the full name of the pool

How it should be: `/projects/${project-number}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/${id-provider}`

And I also added the following command:

```
 gcloud config set account ${{GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}}
```

Before my docker push, because it was required.

In addition, according to the docs https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#usage, my service account was missing the required roles:

- roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
- roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser

Edit: You may also need to grant access for your service account to your Workload Identity Pool, you can do it by command or interface:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
    --role=roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member="MEMBER_ID"
```

Docs:https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#gcloud