# Docker container for google cloudML on compute engine - authenticating for mounting bucket

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, google-container-os

I have been working with google's machine learning platform, `cloudML`.

Big picture:
I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to get their docker [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605801/authenticate-google-cloud-service-account-on-docker-image) up and running on google compute instances, have access to the cloudML API and my storage bucket.

Starting locally, I have my service account configured

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud config list
Your active configuration is: [service]

[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-a
[core]
account = 773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = api-project-773889352370
```

I boot a compute instance with the google container image family

```
gcloud compute instances create gci --image-family gci-stable --image-project google-containers --scopes 773889352370-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
```

EDIT: Need to explicitly set scope for communicating with cloudML.

I can then ssh into that instance (for debugging)

```
gcloud compute ssh benweinstein2010@gci
```

On the compute instance, I can pull the cloudML docker from GCR and run it

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
docker run -it --rm  -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" \
  --entrypoint=/bin/bash \
  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
```

I can confirm I have access to my desired bucket. No credential problems there

```
root@cd6cc28a1c8a:/# gsutil ls gs://api-project-773889352370-ml
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/Ben/
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/Cameras/
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/MeerkatReader/
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/Prediction/
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/TrainingData/
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/cloudmldist/
```

But when I try to mount the bucket

```
root@139e775fcf6b:~# gcsfuse api-project-773889352370-ml /mnt/gcs-bucket
Using mount point: /mnt/gcs-bucket
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: failed to open /dev/fuse: Operation not permitted
```

It must be that I am required to activate my service account from within the docker container? I have had similar (unsolved issues [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605801/authenticate-google-cloud-service-account-on-docker-image))

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account
```

I could pass docker a credentials .json file, but i'm not sure where/if gcloud ssh passes those files to my instance?

I have access to cloud platform more broadly, for example I can post a request to the cloudML API.

```
gcloud beta ml predict --model ${MODEL_NAME} --json-instances images/request.json > images/${outfile}
```

which succeeds. So some credentials are being passed.I guess I could pass it to compute engine, and then from the compute engine to the docker instance? It feels like i'm not using the tools as intended. I thought gcloud would handle this once I authenticated locally.

Comment: Edit: adding explicit scope solves the second problem (connecting to cloudML), but not mounting the bucket inside the docker container

Comment: This is most likely an issue with fuse, GCI, and Docker. Are you trying to run  gcifuse inside the docker container or on the host VM? One problem might be that you didn't start the container in privileged mode.   Try adding the --privileged flag to the docker command.  I'd also suggest rephrasing the question to focus on the fuse and GCI issues. This will help get the attention of the right experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a docker issue, not a gcloud permissions issue. Docker needs to be run as --privileged to allow fuse to mount.